# How To Create An Executable Out Of A Executable Jar File Using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using gradle for my application (a python compiler). I already wrote one before in C++, but I'm thinking of doing another better on in java as I have more knowledge in Java. I'm using gradle to build. So far, here is what my project looks like:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── compiler
    │   │       ├── Lexer.java
    │   │       ├── Main.java
    │   │       └── TableEntry.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── compiler
        │       └── MainTest.java
        └── resources
```

The `Lexer` and `TableEntry` files are not important. Here is what my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'

version '0.1.0'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'python',
        'Implementation-Version': version, 
        'Main-Class': 'compiler.Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}

task deleteBin(type: Delete) {
    doLast {
        new File('bin').deleteDir()
    }
}

tasks.clean.dependsOn(tasks.deleteBin)

tasks.jar.doLast {
    copy {
        from 'build/libs'
        into 'bin'
    }
}
```

What this is supposed to do is build the `Main.java` file into an executable jar and copy it into a directory called `bin`. Which it does do. After I call `./gradlew build`, this is what the tree looks like:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── python-0.1.0.jar
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── java
│   │       ├── main
│   │       │   └── compiler
│   │       │       ├── Lexer.class
│   │       │       ├── Main.class
│   │       │       └── TableEntry.class
│   │       └── test
│   │           └── compiler
│   │               └── MainTest.class
│   ├── generated
│   │   └── sources
│   │       ├── annotationProcessor
│   │       │   └── java
│   │       │       ├── main
│   │       │       └── test
│   │       └── headers
│   │           └── java
│   │               ├── main
│   │               └── test
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── python-0.1.0.jar
│   ├── reports
│   │   └── tests
│   │       └── test
│   │           ├── css
│   │           │   ├── base-style.css
│   │           │   └── style.css
│   │           ├── index.html
│   │           └── js
│   │               └── report.js
│   ├── test-results
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── binary
│   │           ├── output.bin
│   │           ├── output.bin.idx
│   │           └── results.bin
│   └── tmp
│       ├── compileJava
│       │   └── source-classes-mapping.txt
│       ├── compileTestJava
│       │   └── source-classes-mapping.txt
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── compiler
    │   │       ├── Lexer.java
    │   │       ├── Main.java
    │   │       └── TableEntry.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── compiler
        │       └── MainTest.java
        └── resources
```

But I was thinking that people who use my compiler will need java installed to actually use it. In C++, it already compiles it into an executable, which is convenient. With a little research, I found a plugin called `launch4j`, but I couldn't seem to get it to work. What other options do I have to covert my jar file into an executable?

Sorry for not explaining why `launch4j` doesn't work. So I went to the [github repository](https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j) where it said to add this plugin:

```
'edu.sc.seis.launch4j'
```

I added that, and gradle didn't recognize it. The line I put:

```
apply plugin: 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j'
```

The output:

```
Plugin with id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' not found.
```

So then I went to the maven central repository search, and found it again as a dependency over [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/edu.sc.seis.gradle/launch4j/1.0.6/jar). It got added fine when I added this line to my `dependencies` section:

```
implementation 'edu.sc.seis.gradle:launch4j:1.0.6'
```

However, when I tried editing the `launch4j` task like this:

```
launch4j {
}
```

It said that it could not find that task.

```
Could not find method launch4j() for arguments [build_c92xwmoykapsewu0cy351y5ww$_run_closure4@5635a004] on root project 'python' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Comment: I switched from launch4j to winrun4j last year to enable my app to be pinned to the task bar. But beware. This kind of question is likely to get closed because it's going to elicit opinions. I've tried to state only a fact and that might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

launch4j is fine. It's a bit odd that you found a tool that describes precisely what you want, and all you have to say about it is: "... it doesn't work".

A few notes to help you out with launch4j:

- This is, of course, solely for windows.
- You still need to ship an entire VM. It's never going to be a single executable; java is not that kind of tool.
- You'd need an installer that places the exe (made by launch4j) + a VM + all your deps in a single location.

You'd end up with something like:

```
C:\Program Files\MyApp\myapp.exe
C:\Program Files\MyApp\jvm\(a bunch of files here; an entire JRE/JDK installation)
C:\Program Files\MyApp\lib\dep1.jar
C:\Program Files\MyApp\lib\dep2.jar
```

The dependencies are of course optional and can be striped in too.

You can then tell launch4j to use that VM and not whatever's already installed (if any). This also has the convenient side-effect of being compatible with the current 'model' of running java apps on desktops (which is that you, the app vendor, are responsible for VM distribution and not oracle+the end user, which was how it more or less worked until java8, which is outdated), and also that you know precisely which version you're running on.

Starting with java 11 you can use jlink to make 'treeshaken' custom VMs: These contain juuust the bits of the VM you actually end up using. You do need to switch to a modular build (which involves making a `module-info.java` file - plenty of tutorials to be found if you really want to go this route).

I have no idea if you can make such treeshaken VMs work together with launch4j, but you should be able to.

I am not aware of any solutions for linux and mac.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I edited my question to explain just exactly how launch4j doesn't work.

Comment: It's not true that you need to ship a VM. It can use a Java that is installed separatedly.

Comment: @JeffHolt Yes; but OP doesn't want that. I was trying to convey that if you want launch4j to make you something that can run on a target machine regardless of what they have or have not installed, you have to ship a JRE along with it.